# How to call an imagepicker delegate using parentcontroller class on iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

mainclass.m

```
-(void)gotoMainViewforpickphoto:(id)currentview{

    picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    picker=nil;        
}
```

Actually, I have an imagepicker class. I do a check: If the camera is not available, I have to show a photo library by using `presentModalViewController`.

But I want to hide logos and logout at top of view. So, using parentcontroler I write the method in `mainclass`. I get the photo library. When I click an image, the delegates are not called. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the `UIImagePickerController`'s delegate, so it makes sense that the delegate methods are not being called.

You need to add:

```
picker.delegate = self;
```

Or, if `self` is not the delegate of the UIImagePickerController, replace `self` with whatever you want your delegate to be.

Comment: thanks. bt in i want use delegates of imagepickercontroller in imagepickerclas only. i dont want use in mainclas

Comment: for showing presentmodalview controller, thatswhy i went to mainclas.rest of things i want use in imagepicker clas only

Comment: You mean an imagepicker class that you created? You still need to make it the UIImagePicker's delegate so that it gets the delegate methods called to it.